# Combinatorial constructions found by computer

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, computer-science

In preparation for a talk I am giving to our undergraduate mathematics society, I am trying to collect examples of combinatorial constructions that were found by computer. Thus my question is the following.

**What are the most notable examples of combinatorial constructions found by computer search?**

For example, one fertile area for such results is lower bounds on Ramsey numbers, for example [this recent paper](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v22i3p11) by Exoo and Tatarevic. (But since I am looking for constructions, computer-assisted upper bounds on Ramsey numbers don't count.)

Another non-example would be Aubrey de Grey's [construction](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385) of a unit-distance graph on 1581 vertices with chromatic number 5 (thereby showing that the [chromatic number of the plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem) is at least 5), since the graph was constructed by hand.

Comment: Is this a call for research cooperation (in which case it does not belong here), or do you have a specific question that we can actually answer?

Comment: One quick one: Ahmad Abu-Khazneh found (by computer search) an example of a (presumably!) extremal 4-uniform hypergraph for Ryser's conjecture with matching number 2 which doesn't partition into extremal examples with matching number 1. The relevance of this is that for 3-uniform hypergraphs it's known all extremal examples (for any matching number) do so partition, and it was believed this would hold for higher uniformities too.

Comment: Another general area is small combinatorial designs: many examples exist where the construction involved substantial amounts of computer search. Look in the Journal of Combinatorial Designs at any paper proving the existence of a specific small design; this is likely to be an example for your question.

Comment: You might enjoy https://mathoverflow.net/q/12085 .  An answer I posted there may be notable as it was an undergraduate (Roger House) who initiated the search for matrices of various determinants.  Gerhard "Still More To Be Found" Paseman, 2018.09.20.

Comment: I have a few non-notable examples in one of my papers regarding counter-examples...

Comment: Do you care about the significance of the results? There are some very niche (maybe 5 people active in it) research areas that currently rely on computing (essentially) combinatorial data to make progress.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know how notable this would be but here is another example from my paper ["16,051 formulas for Ottaviani's invariant of cubic threefolds"](https://arxiv.org/abs/1402.2669) with Christian Ikenmeyer and Gordon Royle, published in J. Algebra 2016. It is this graph:
[image]

It represents the $SL_5$-invariant of degree 15 of cubics in 5 variables.
It was found by a computer search of $1-(15,5,3)$ design with certain desired chromatic properties.

Answer (score 8):

There is a beautiful story involving the faithfulness question of the Burau representation of the braid group.

Moody showed that the Burau representation is unfaithful if $n$ (the number of strands) is at least 10. The method involved a beautiful reduction to an existence question for a simple closed curve, with certain unusual intersecton properties. Long and Patton improved this to $n \ge 6$ by finding more curves.

Bigelow did extensive computer calculations and found such an exceptional curve for $n=5$, thus showing unfaithfulness for this $n$. He also found a ridiculously simple example for $n = 6$:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9904100.pdf

Answer (score 6):

there are results in graph theory of this sort, essentially enumerating all the graphs on at most N vertices with such and such properties, and seeing that there are none/some.

E.g. fullerens (modeled by planar graphs with certain  properties) might nice topic, see
https://doi.org/10.1006/jagm.1996.0806

the most famous computer-based result in graph theory is probably 4-color theorem
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem

My humble self constructed few interesting graphs and digraphs on computer (although then publishing (mostly) "computer-free" proofs).
https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aim.2017.03.029
https://doi.org/10.1016/0097-3165(95)90062-4

similarly, in finite group theory (which is quite combinatorial subject in a way)  one might look in a  complete database and reach some conclusion...

Comment: Are there examples of published papers with such results? Any references?

Comment: I added few (posting from a phone - not easy :))

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest browsing through the issues of [Experimental Mathematics](https://www.tandfonline.com/loi/uexm20?close=27&year=2018&repitition=0#vol_27_2018), which has many examples of the kind you seek. (Full disclosure: I am an editor, so you may construe this as tooting my own horn).

Comment: I have a submission there with this type of examples regarding polytopes, so you're tooting my horn as well, so its fair :)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure whether this counts as combinatorial: there are several equations for generating functions that were found by computer.  I think
*Bostan, Alin; Kauers, Manuel; Van Hoeij, Mark*, [**The complete generating function for Gessel walks is algebraic**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-2010-10398-2), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 138, No. 9, 3063-3078 (2010). [ZBL1206.05013](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1206.05013).
and its predecessor

*Kauers, Manuel; Koutschan, Christoph; Zeilberger, Doron*, [**Proof of Ira Gessel’s lattice path conjecture**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.0901678106), Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 106, No. 28, 11502-11505 (2009). [ZBL1203.05010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1203.05010).
is very nice.

Personally, I am very fond of [Exact formulas for the partition function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47611/exact-formulas-for-the-partition-function/47706#47706)

Answer (score 4):

My group, [The Permuta Triangle](https://ulfarsson.github.io/permuta_triangle/main_page.html), has been working on automating the discovery of combinatorial specifications. Some of the discovered results for pattern avoiding permutations, set partitions and (soon) Motzkin paths can be viewed at the [ComboPal website](http://combopal.ru.is). Click "Random" in the left hand corner to go on a tour of specifications!

Answer (score 3):

Many coverings in [La Jolla Covering Repository](https://www.ccrwest.org/cover.html) were found by computer.

Answer (score 3):

The bijection in

*Rubey, Martin; Stump, Christian*, [**Double deficiencies of Dyck paths via the Billey-Jockusch-Stanley bijection**](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL20/Stump/stump7.html), J. Integer Seq. 20, No. 9, Article 17.9.6, 9 p. (2017). [ZBL1384.05048](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1384.05048).

was essentially found by computer.

Answer (score 2):

Emmanuel Jeandel, Michael Rao, *An aperiodic set of 11 Wang tiles*,
https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.06492